# GridSearchCV does not report scores on verbose mode

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running a parameter grid with GridSearchCV on python 3.8.5 and sklearn 0.24.1:

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=xg_clf, scoring=make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef), param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=args.n_jobs, verbose = 3)
```

according to the documentation,

```
 |  verbose : int
 |      Controls the verbosity: the higher, the more messages.
 |  
 |      - >1 : the computation time for each fold and parameter candidate is
 |        displayed;
 |      - >2 : the score is also displayed;
 |      - >3 : the fold and candidate parameter indexes are also displayed
 |        together with the starting time of the computation.
```

setting `verbose = 3`, which I did, should print the Matthews Correlation Coefficient for each run.

However, the output is

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 480 candidates, totalling 2400 fits
[CV 1/5] END colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.7, max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.9; total time=   0.2s
[CV 2/5] END colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.7, max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.9; total time=   0.2s
[CV 3/5] END colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.7, max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.9; total time=   0.2s
[CV 4/5] END colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.7, max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.9; total time=   0.2s
[CV 5/5] END colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.7, max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.9; total time=   0.2s
[CV 1/5] END colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.7, max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.95; total time=   0.2s
```

why isn't `GridSearchCV` printing the MCC for each run?

Maybe this is because I'm using a non-standard scorer?

Comment: Are you working on Google Colab? Also, make sure to update your library to match the documentation you quoted.

Comment: @ArturoSbr I've never heard of Google Colab.  The documentation is from the command line on my laptop.

Comment: I mentioned Google Colab because it's a platform where verbose does not seem to work well. Either way, is `xg_clf` an xgboost object? If so, that may be the reason why.

Comment: @ArturoSbr `xg_clf` is indeed an XGBoost object.  Does XGBoost work with GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried something similar to your code with a few different sklearn versions. As it turns out, version 0.24.1 does not print out the scores when `verbose=3`.

Here's my code and output with sklearn version 0.22.2.post1:

```py
clf = XGBClassifier()
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, scoring=make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef),
                      param_grid={'max_depth':[3, 4, 5]}, verbose=3)
search.fit(X, y)

> Fitting 5 folds for each of 3 candidates, totalling 15 fits
  [CV] max_depth=3 .....................................................
  [CV] ......................... max_depth=3, score=0.959, total=   0.2s
```

Here's my code and output with sklearn version 0.24.1:

```py
clf = XGBClassifier()
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, scoring=make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef),
                      param_grid={'max_depth':[3, 4, 5]}, verbose=3)
search.fit(X, y)

> Fitting 5 folds for each of 3 candidates, totalling 15 fits
  [CV 1/5] END ....................................max_depth=3; total time=   0.2s
```

In conclusion, you found a bug. Normally, I would recommend opening an issue on GitHub, but you'll be happy to know that version 0.24.2 **does** print the scores for each fold.

You can try `pip install scikit-learn --upgrade` or `pip install scikit-learn==0.24.2` to fix this error.